# Determining the name of the HAL that is installed on Windows 7 SP1 32-bit

Tags: windows, device-driver

I am trying to install just checked HAL and kernel on Windows 7 SP 1 32-bit. The instruction on the Microsoft Dev Center web site [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) suggests I do the following:

1. Open the file %SystemRoot%\Inf\setupapi.dev.log and search for hal.dll.
   You should find a line like TargetFilename - 'hal.dll'
2. In the same section of the log file, look for the corresponding SourceFilename. The name to the right of SourceFilename is the name of the HAL file that you need to copy from the checked build.

setupapi.dev.log file on my machine, however, does not mention hal.dll. In fact, I searched for hal.dll in the inf directory and found no mention of it in any other log file.

I did find mentions of acpi_hal and ACPIAPIC_HAL in setupapi.dev.log, but I'm not sure if this can help me select the correct hal.

Is there any other way to determine which hal to use?

EDIT: I figured it out. See below.

Comment: It's not called hal.dll in the example on the wen page you provided either. Says something like hal.dll.

Comment: I was looking for anything that had 'hal' and 'dll' in it, something like this:

SourceFilename - 'halmacpi.dll'

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In *Windows Internals*, 6th Edition, on page 60, there's a list of x86 HALs: 
Halacpi.dll - Advanced Configuration and Power Interface (ACPI) uniprocessor-only machines. 
Halmacpi.dll - Advanced Programmable Interrupt Controller (APIC) with ACPI.

Since my computer is multiprocessor and because ACPIAPIC_HAL was listed in the log file, I tried halmacpi.dll and it worked.

Thanks.