# mouse hook broke all windows input

Tags: c++, windows

I'm new to c++ programming and am trying to make a small reporting tool that will detect when the mouse and keyboard haven't been touched over a period of time.

I have been searching for some example mouse hook code and found this

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0400
#pragma comment( lib, "user32.lib" )

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

HHOOK hMouseHook;

__declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardEvent (int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT * pMouseStruct = (MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam;
    if (pMouseStruct != NULL)
        printf("Mouse position X = %d  Mouse Position Y = %d\n", pMouseStruct->pt.x,pMouseStruct->pt.y);
    return CallNextHookEx(hMouseHook,
        nCode,wParam,lParam);
}

void MessageLoop()
{
    MSG message;
    while (GetMessage(&message,NULL,0,0)) {
        TranslateMessage( &message );
        DispatchMessage( &message );
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI MyMouseLogger(LPVOID lpParm)
{
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    if (!hInstance) hInstance = LoadLibrary((LPCSTR) lpParm);
    if (!hInstance) return 1;

    hMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx ( 
        WH_MOUSE_LL,
        (HOOKPROC) KeyboardEvent, 
        hInstance,                
        NULL                      
        );
    MessageLoop();
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hMouseHook);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    HANDLE hThread;
    DWORD dwThread;

    hThread = CreateThread(NULL,NULL,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)
        MyMouseLogger, (LPVOID) argv[0], NULL, &dwThread);
    if (hThread)
        return WaitForSingleObject(hThread,INFINITE);
    else return 1;
}
```

I compiled and ran this as a test which seems to do what I wanted. After that I started testing a couple of things. compiled on c++ and g++ for the hell of it. removed the pMouseStruct and tested "if(lParam)" instead. Everything seemed to be behaving and it was getting late so I decided to return to this the next day.

When I booted in to windows today, I was unable to move the mouse or input anything with the keyboard. It seems input inside windows (normal and safe mode) is not working anymore. Any ideas how to fix this?

Using Windows 7 64bit.

So far I have tried the following:
- reversed a recent overclocking tweak.
- returned the code to the way it was before i played with it, recompiled, and ran.
- Googling.
- chkdsk /f on the system drive.
- system restore (doesn't like raid)
- copied user32.dll off a friend.

Plz forgive my ignorance :-)

Comment: By the way, it's probably easier to do by using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646302(v=vs.85).aspx). It's up to you, though. Both ways have their advantages.

Comment: Thanks Chris. That looks like a more fitting option. Will look into it after I fix windows.

Comment: If you did not script or configure it to be started while system startup, then you might have **nothing to do with the code currently**. Recovering the corrupt things it has caused is prior than **what the code is**.

Comment: You can not copy from others machine. But you make a new copy of installation of OS with another drive on the same machine. Then copy the file from the new one. DVDs would not contains HAL.DLL they might have different name I told, like HALACPI.DL_, and in a compressed manner.

Comment: Take a look at [Determining the name of the HAL that is installed on Windows 7 SP1 32-bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186728/determining-the-name-of-the-hal-that-is-installed-on-windows-7-sp1-32-bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling windows 7 and soon ran into more strange problems. I have since discovered that standby was corrupting various things and have stopped using it. Now I'm running a fresh install of windows 7 that has never been put to sleep. Still don't have any bizarre problems to this day :-)